# How to count the number of distinct items over multiple many-to-many table relationships?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

So I have 3 main tables (the data is not important):

- Customer
- Group
- Employee

And a couple of "many-to-many" tables to join the other 3 tables:

- GroupCustomer
- GroupEmployee

In essence, a customer can belong to many groups, and an employee can belong to many groups.

So now lets say I have queried for a specific Customer. So I have something like:

```
Customer customer1 = GetCustomer1();
```

Now I want to get a count of distinct employees that are in any group that the customer is also in...

```
int count = customer1.GroupCustomers.SomeLinqMagicGoesHere
```

So, what is the Linq magic that I need?

**important**: The relationships are generated using linq-to-sql

---

Some desired input/output if it help explain my needs:

```
Customer
--------
C1
C2

GroupCustomer
--------
C1 | G1
C1 | G2
C2 | G1

Group
--------
G1
G2

GroupEmployee
--------
E1 | G1
E1 | G2
E2 | G2

Employee
--------
E1
E2
```

So the count number I want for C1 should be 2. And the count for C2 should be 1.

Hope that hasn't confused the issue more!

Comment: What does GroupCustomers return?

Comment: @Blam: Should have said (which I have added in). The relationships, such as `GroupCustomers` is generated via linq-to-sql (dbml file)

Comment: But C2 is in G2 that has two distinct employees

Comment: @Blam: Correct again! But atleast you understand my requirements it seems (updated question to fix)

Comment: Any comment on the downvotes? Is there something wrong with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe:

```
int count = costumer.GroupCustomers
    .SelectMany(gc => gc.Group.GroupEmployees)
    .Select(ge => ge.EmployeeID)
    .Distinct()
    .Count();
```

Comment: You have to go through the many-to-many tables (i.e. GroupCustomer) which you have not included

Answer (score 0):

If your mapping is correct, you should be able to get the count of distinct Employees in a group the customer is in simply like this :

```
customer1.Groups.SelectMany(x => x.Employees).Distinct().Count()
```

Comment: `customer1` does not have a `Groups` property. It must go through `GroupCustomers` first